# Hangfire job filter configuration in appsettings.json

Tags: hangfire

I have created a job filter attribute for Hangfire that will do some work before and after a job executes. The attribute looks similar to this:

```cs
public class MyJobAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter
{
    public MyJobAttribute(string someConfig)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The attribute is added to a job method like this:

```cs
[MyJob("very important string")]
public void Test()
{
    // Do the job
}
```

Everything works fine. The job filter is called before and after the job. Now I want to move the `very important string` to the `appsettings.json` file. I read somewhere that I can register the job filter globally and then inject an `IConfiguration`. But I would like to include this attribute on a specific job and do something similar to this:

```cs
[MyJob("%thekey%")]
public void Test()
{
    // Do the job
}
```

And then in the `appsettings.json` file do like this:

```json
{
    "thekey": "very important string"
}
```

Is this possible in any way or perhaps even built-in?

Comment: You could pass "thekey" in your attribute constructor and then resolve Configuration["theKey"] when needed ?

Comment: Yeah, that could be an option. Do you know if I have access to Configuration from within my attribute somehow?

Comment: This should help :
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/dependency-injection-for-filter-attribute-non-global/6809/6?u=jblagorce
Register a filter (with its dependencies, including Configuration) which will check for a given passive [MyJob("thekey")] attribute on filterContext.BackgroundJob.Job.Method, will retrieve "thekey and then "Configuration["thekey"] and do its business depending on it.